# How to display the data that available in database using exist() query

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have this Code. But I need to display the values that exists in the database, Not like "It's Exists in the Database", I need to display the values of that given email_id.

```
def post(request): 
if request.method == 'GET':
    value = example.objects.all()
    email_id = request.GET.get('email_id', None)      
    if example.objects.filter(email_id = email_id).exists():
        
         tutorials_serializer = exampleSerializer(value, many=True)
         return JsonResponse(tutorials_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Pls help me through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there - You need to filter your `values`, not just check there is something in the filtered qs.

```
def post(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        email_id = request.GET.get('email_id', None)      
        values = example.objects.filter(email_id=email_id)
        if values.exists():
            tutorials_serializer = exampleSerializer(value, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(tutorials_serializer.data, safe=False)
        return <Some default response that you want when nothing exists>
```

Comment: Its Working But in the post Method i am creating new record with the same email_id its creating another data with that email. I want to check that in new creation of data it want o show that email_id is already there.

Comment: That's a different question really, but I would suggest you set the `email` field as `unique=True` on the model. Also look at the method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create , which may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def post(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        value = example.objects.all()
        email_id = request.GET.get('email_id', None)
        if email_id: 
            queryset = example.objects.filter(email_id = email_id)
            if queryset.exists():
                tutorials_serializer = exampleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                return JsonResponse(tutorials_serializer.data, safe=False)
```